# How to dismiss keyboard when the UISearch Bar 'Search" button is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

I've implemented a UISearch bar with the searching functionality set up, however when I press the "Search" button on the keyboard that shows up nothing happens. How can I get the keyboard to hide when the "Search" button is pressed while keeping the text in the search bar intact (To keep the search results present)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From *[Text, Web and Editing Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW4)*:

> To dismiss the keyboard, you call the resignFirstResponder method of the text-based view that is currently the first responder.

So you should do this in your `UISearchBarDelegate`:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    // Do the search...
}
```

Comment: That works only partially for me because if I resign first responder the cancel button gets disabled...it doesn't keep it enabled to receive touches.

Comment: The UISearchBar's cancel button exists to provide a way for iPhone users to dismiss the keyboard, since the iPhone keyboard doesn't have a dismiss button.  If you need a cancel button for some other reason, you have to implement it yourself as UISearchBar doesn't give you full access to that control.

Comment: I got this error message, fatal error: Array index out of range

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

 Make sure you have UISearchBarDelegate defined in your UIViewController

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```